# Node.js installation: Should it be nodejs or node.js?

Tags: node.js

After launching an ec2 Ubuntu 16.04 instance on AWS, I have both:

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

and:

```
apt-get install node.js
```

Both are runnable but each shows different disk usage.  Which should be the correct one to install Node.js? (Why are there two? How different are they?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding required PPA file you should write `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
to install node.js

This will allow you to easily install modules and packages to use with node.js

Because of a conflict with another package, the executable from the Ubuntu repositories is called nodejs instead of node. Keep this in mind as you are running software.

ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing nvm: It removes loads of the issues relating to installing via package manager

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

you can then use the command `nvm list` to get the versions of node available then use command `nvm install <version>` to install a specific version, then `nvm use <version>` to use that version for what you are doing.  e.g.

`nvm install 8.1.2 && nvm use 8.1.2`